# Using (real) Android device as Webcam for BlueStacks?

Tags: bluestacks, webcam

I'm using BlueStacks emulator on my desktop. Is there a way to use my android device as a webcam for BlueStacks? A details approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bluestacks does not have support for any video or audio input.